# Why are python strings left aligned in format with specified width?

Tags: python, string, formatting

While thinking of a way to pretty print table header i found that integers are right aligned by default, but strings are left aligned.

For example:

```
>>> for i in (1,'x',0.0):
...     print("{0:5}".format(i))
... 
    1
x    
  0.0
```

This is easily fixed by setting alignment explicitly, but i wonder why is this so?

EDIT:

I am not looking for a way to align strings, it is easy:

```
>>> for i in (1,'x',0.0):
...     print("{0:>5}".format(i))
... 
    1
    x
  0.0
```

I just thought that all objects would be aligned the same way by deafult and i'm asking why is it not so.

Comment: I think it's just considered natural.  It's the standard formatting in most spreadsheet programs, too.

Answer (score 1):

Was going through the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). No clue what so ever for this.

Just a wild guess - We read text left-right so strings

Comment: And we read numbers some other way? I don't think that this is related.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for something like this

```
print ( "%5s" % ('x',) )
print ( "%5d" % (245,) )
```

which outputs

```
    x
  245
```

For the question 'why' I think an answer is that when you read some data in column you actually expect string to be left aligned

```
a
ab
abc
```

and not

```
   a
  ab
 abc
```

Also text in books is left aligned. For number most natural formatting is right aligned

```
  7
 45
156
```

Which for istance is the way of arranging numbers for sum, subtraction and multiplication. Python choice actually reflects typographic conventions. Mixing text and numbers in a table may be considered a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 syntax (available in 2.6, too)

```
>>> print("{foo:>5s}\n{bar:>5d}".format(foo="a", bar=100))
    a
  100
```

Read the [format spec](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). The alignment specifier here is the `>`.